# How do I enlarge the menu bottons?

Tags: menu

I want the menu buttons (close, minimise, and restore/maximise) to be bigger so that they're more visible and the clickable area is bigger too.

If that includes increasing the size of the entire menu bar itself, then I'm up for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to first increase the thickness of the menu bar, then second to change the icon size (replace the small icons with bigger icons) for the close, min, and restore buttons.  You can use the answers at these two pages to accomplish that:

[Increase Menu Bar Size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342734/increase-menu-bar-size)

[How can I get bigger window buttons in unity ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475651/how-can-i-get-bigger-window-buttons-in-unity)

Comment: Is there no other way?